# Why is this stochastic process a Markov chain?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, conditional-probability

Suppose we have an independent sequence $(X_n)$ such that $P(X_n=1)=P(X_n=0)=\cfrac{1}{2}$

Let $M_n=(X_{n-1},X_n)$.

The exercise I'm working on supposes that $(M_n)_{n \ge 2}$ is a markov chain but it didn't make sense to me because if we have for example

$M_4=(X_4,X_3)$ , $M_3=(X_3,X_2)$ , $M_2=(X_2,X_1)$

then $(M_n)$ is a markov chain iff

$P(M_4=m_4 | M_3=m_3,M_2=(1,1))=P(M_4=m_4 | M_3=m_3)$ but that didn't make sense to me since the value of $M_3$ also depends on $M_2$ since they share $X_2$. In other words, if we were to change $X_2$ in $M_2$ to $(0,1)$ then wouldn't $M_3$ change? What am I getting wrong exactly?

**Edit**:

Other than that problem, I was asked to give and graph the transition matrix $P$. How am I going to do that given that the state space is $E=\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}$

Comment: One of the ways to understand that $M_n$ is the Markov chain, is to see that $M_n$ does not depend on $M_{n-2}$ and $M_{n-3}$ and so on. It only depends on $M_{n-1}$. But this is the definition of a Markov chain. If you know the present ($M_{n-1}$), the future $M_{n}$ does not depend on the past (which is $M_{n-2}$,$M_{n-3}$...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ambiguity on the shared coordinates between $M_3$ and $M_2$ is understandable; they share $X_2$ and can no way be regarded as independent. But, note that both $M_3$ and $M_2$ are present as conditions in $P(M_4=m_4 | M_3=m_3,M_2=(1,1))=P(M_4=m_4 | M_3=m_3)$ and once this is done, the dependence between $M_3$ and $M_2$ vanishes. So we have
$$
P\Big[M_4=(a,b) | M_3=(c,d),M_2=(e,f)\Big]
\\{=\begin{cases}
P[M_4=(a,b) | M_3=(b,d),M_2=(d,f)]&,\quad b=c \ \ \ ,\ \ d=e\\
0&,\quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\\=\begin{cases}
P[M_4=(a,b) | M_3=(b,d)]&,\quad b=c \ \ \ ,\ \ d=e\\
0&,\quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
}
$$
Note that if the transition matrix for $M_i$ is requested, then you will end up with a $4\times 4$ matrix, since each $M_i$ can possess $4$ different levels. If we arrange these levels as $0:(0,0),1:(0,1),2:(1,0),3:(1,1)$, then we have
$$
P=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}&0&\frac{1}{2}&0\\
0&\frac{1}{2}&0&\frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2}&0&\frac{1}{2}&0\\
0&\frac{1}{2}&0&\frac{1}{2}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

You're doing your test for independence wrong.  You should be checking
$$P(M_4 = m_4 \cap M_2 = m_2 \mid M_3=m_3) = P(M_4 = m_4 \mid M_3=m_3) P(M_2=m_2 \mid M_3=m_3).$$
When it's impossible for $M_2 = m_2$ and $M_3 = m_3$ at the same time, this will give you the equation $0 = 0$.

Comment: I don't totally get your answer. If you were to prove that this is a Markov chain how would you do it? I thought I used the definition so I'm not sure why it's wrong

Comment: Just make sure $P(M_4=a|M_3=b,M_2=c)=P(M_4=a|M_3=b)$ for each $a,b,c$.  Note $b$ and $c$ need to be compatible (i.e. the 1st state in $c$ has to be equal to the 2nd state in $b$) otherwise on the left hand side you are *conditioning* on something that cannot happen which is a no-no, so ignore those cases and prove it for the rest.